# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'glfwGetCurrentContext'

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, mujoco

I'm trying a tutorial on Reinforcement learning wherein I'm currently trying to use gymnasium, mujoco, to train agents. I've installed mujoco and when I try to run the program, the sim window opens for a second and throws this error. Idk what I'm doing wrong.

```
import gymnasium as gym
import stable_baselines3
import imageio



env=gym.make('Humanoid-v4', render_mode='human')
obs=env.reset()
env.render()
print(obs)
```

BTW, I'm getting the output of print(obs) which returns a tensor. It's just the sim environment which is throwing this error.

Error Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\envs\learn\lib\site-packages\gymnasium\envs\mujoco\mujoco_rendering.py", line 337, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\envs\learn\lib\site-packages\gymnasium\envs\mujoco\mujoco_rendering.py", line 330, in free
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\envs\learn\lib\site-packages\glfw\__init__.py", line 2358, in get_current_context
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'glfwGetCurrentContext'
```

Comment: What is the full error traceback? You could edit your question to include it.

Comment: Hey, I've included it now. Please do tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. I completely abandoned mujoco and instead am now working with pybullet. Pybullet fortunately hasn't thrown such errors as of yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue when I was trying to use `Walker2d-v4`. The error message I received was:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_current_context'
```

This led me to believe that the issue might be a compatibility problem between `gymnasium` and the version of `mujoco` you are using. In my case, downgrading the `mujoco` package resolved the problem. It seems that `gymnasium` might not be fully compatible with `mujoco-3.0.0` yet.

Here's what you can do to potentially resolve the issue:

1. **install proper version of mujoco package:**

   ```
   pip install mujoco==2.3.7
   ```
2. **Download the corresponding version of mujoco:**

   You can find the release [here](https://github.com/google-deepmind/mujoco/releases/tag/2.3.7).

3. **Extract the downloaded package:**

   Place it in a directory such as `/home/[user-name]/.mujoco`.
4. **Set the necessary environment variables:**

   ```bash
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/[your-user-name]/.mujoco/mujoco2.3.7/bin:/usr/lib/nvidia
   export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so
   ```

   Make sure to replace `[your-user-name]` with your actual username.